# How to sort encrypted column data?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, encryption, sql-order-by

I have done searching for encrypted and non-encrypted columns but for ordering non-encrypted fields are ordering successfully but encrypted fields are not sorting.

Encrypted columns: firstname, lastname, email

Encrypt Function

```
// Encrypt Data
function encrypted_data($decrypted){
    if($decrypted != NULL){
        $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
        // Must be exact 32 chars (256 bit)
        $salt = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $password = substr(hash('sha256', $salt, true), 0, 32);
        // IV must be exact 16 chars (128 bit)
        $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($decrypted, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
        return $encrypted;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

code for searching

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) && isset($_POST['search']['value']) && !empty($_POST['search']['value']))
{
    $search_keyword = trim($_POST['search']['value']);
    $encrypted = encrypted_data($search_keyword);
    
    $search_query = "AND id like '%$search_keyword%' OR pin_local_id like '%$search_keyword%' OR firstname like '%$encrypted%' OR lastname like '%$encrypted%' OR email like '%$encrypted%'";

    $sql .= $search_query;
    $count_sql .= $search_query;
}
```

code for ordering

```
if(isset($_POST['order'][0]['dir']))
{
    $db_orderby = $_POST['order'][0]['dir'];

    if( isset($_POST['order'][0]['column']) && $_POST['order'][0]['column'] == 1 ) {
        $db_field_name = 'ID';
        $sql .= " order by $db_field_name $db_orderby ";
    } else if( isset($_POST['order'][0]['column']) && $_POST['order'][0]['column'] == 2 ) {
        $db_field_name = 'pin_local_id';
        $sql .= " order by $db_field_name $db_orderby ";
    } else if( isset($_POST['order'][0]['column']) && $_POST['order'][0]['column'] == 3 ) {
        $db_field_data = $_REQUEST['columns'][3]['data'];
        $db_field_name = 'firstname';
        $sql .= " order by $db_field_name $db_orderby ";
    } else if( isset($_POST['order'][0]['column']) && $_POST['order'][0]['column'] == 4 ) {
        $db_field_name = 'lastname';
        $sql .= " order by $db_field_name $db_orderby ";
    } else if( isset($_POST['order'][0]['column']) && $_POST['order'][0]['column'] == 5 ) {
        $db_field_name = 'email';
        $sql .= " order by $db_field_name $db_orderby ";
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY ID ASC ";
}
```

Comment: What order are you expecting for encrypted columns?

Comment: @NigelRen ASC & DESC both as per post request

Comment: What order does it currently display in as you say *encrypted fields are not sorting*?

Comment: Not entirely sure that sorting the encrypted data is a sensible thing to do.  Surely it's encrypted for some reason and so shouldn't be used for something like sorting.

Comment: @NigelRen $_POST['order'][0]['dir'] posts ASC and DESC strings to order column data.. Currently all non-encrypted data is sorting but encrypted data not sorting properly

Comment: You encrypted it so at that point it's *completely opaque to MySQL* by design. They cannot be sorted.

Comment: There is an Order Preserving Encryption that CryptDB also used. Keep in mind that these leak information about the encrypted data like min element, max element, and so on. You may find MySQL external function could be helpful on implementation of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is encrypted in `PHP` you can not use the `MYSQL` to sort, because MYSQL would sort the data by the encrypted `base64` not the original value. MYSQL is never exposed to the original, decrypted value, and therefore will never be able to sort based on it.

You need to retrieve the encrypted data from Mysql, decrypt it in PHP, then manually sort the array using `usort` based on the value of the decrypted data.

Comment: Actually, we can trick MySQL to sort the column as done in CryptDB by using the Order Preserving encryption.